# jQuery not working after an error is thrown into page with validation

Tags: jquery

I am using the below jquery with a form

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.alloy-select-one-menu').change(function(){
          $(this).closest( ".packs_cont" ).find('.alloy-select-one-menu').not(this).prop("selectedIndex", 0);
         });
    });
```

This is working first time but jquery not calling after  if any validation failure thrown into the page. Please help how can I resolve this issue

Comment: Does your form reloads after validation errors?

Comment: no the page is not reloading.

Comment: Can you create jsbin or codepen?

Comment: Post your html and make snippet

Comment: I am sorry , I am not do the same as it violate security policies, I am using this jquery inside a jsf page. On click of submit , backend validation will happen and throw error into page if any validation failure occurs. After that jquery not calling. My Jquey snippet is only this much in the question.

Comment: _“I am sorry , I am not do the same as it violate security policies”_ - if you can’t provide a proper example, you came to the wrong site to ask. (If there is any content involved that could identify a particular client/project/whatever - then replace it with something else.) Go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. If you can’t provide that, because you have to “protect” any of your data - then go hire someone to fix your issue, they will happily sign an NDA.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your form reloads(not whole page) after validation errors, you can't do this as normal event, because after reload form, event is not attached to input. Try to do this as delegate

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('change', '.alloy-select-one-menu', function() {
        $(this).closest( ".packs_cont" ).find('.alloy-select-one-menu').not(this).prop("selectedIndex", 0);;
    });
});
```

@edit

If attaching this to `form` doesn't work, try to attach it to `body`

```
$('body').on('change', '.alloy-select-one-menu', function() {
……
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , This  ('body').on('change'  worked. :)